# How to start server in debug mode - Pycharm

Tags: python, django

I want to debug my code and put breakpoints. However I am not able to start my server in debug mode.

I have a setup.sh file. It has multiple export statements and last statement is python manage.py runserver. In manage.py I added DEBUG = True as shown below :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
 DEBUG = True
```

The application did not stop on debug points i had put.

Comment: The debug setting has nothing at all to do with setting breakpoints, you need to add a configuration to run your project in pycharm

Comment: How would that be done? I run setup.sh file to start my server. This sh file has some export statements and in the ned of the file there is python manage.py runserver

Comment: pycharms docs have a good explanation on how to do so, the SH file isn't needed since you can specify exports in the config (although you can still use it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you may use the python "pdb" debugger.
Just import pdb and call pdb.set_trace() below the line which might cause error.
It will stop at the that point of code during execution and you can debug and see whatever you want to!